# Add a conditioned output column to Powershell Active Diectory Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a Powershell script to query Active Directory Information, so far it Looks like this:

```powershell
$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -Server SERVERNAME 
    -Properties whenChanged,extensionAttribute14
$result | select DistinguishedName,SamAccountName,extensionAttribute14,
    @{N='When Changed'; E={($_.whenChanged).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}}
```

The extensionAttribute14 field in the Active Directory contains some Client specific flags in form of a binary string.

For example: 
0100 means -> Client meets condition A
0101 means -> Client meets condition B

What I Need to do is to add a seperate column to the select Statement that translates the result of the ExtensionAttribute14 field.

Example Output:

`DistinguishedName,SamAccountName,extensionAttribute14,extensionAttribute14Translated,When Changed
CN=CN....,SAM.....,0100,ConditionA,08.09.2014`

How would the select Statement needed to be altered to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a hashtable with results you evaluate on the fly in the `Select-Object` statement:

```powershell
$flags = @{"0100" = "Client meets condition A"; 
    "0101" = "Client meets condition B"}

$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} -Server SERVERNAME 
    -Properties whenChanged,extensionAttribute14  |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName,SamAccountName,
    @{N="extensionAttribute14Translated"; E={$flags.Item($_.extensionAttribute14)}},
    @{N='When Changed'; E={($_.whenChanged).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}}
```

Comment: thanks, that works great. Is it possible to work with Wildcards in the hashtable? For example "*100" = "Client meets condition A"? I already tested it this way but maybe * is not the correct Wildcard?

Comment: You cannot use wildcards on hash table's keys. Using `$flags.getEnumerator()` function you could iterate through objects in the table and do things like `$_.Name -match "100"`. More on hash tables here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx